# Question about syllabification

Tags: phonétique

Can someone explain why would we syllabize 
*constant* as /kɔ̃-stɑ̃/, so V$CCV but *actif* as /ak-tif/ (VC$CV)? French tends to have open syllables so why wouldn't we syllabize *actif* as /a-ktif/?

Merci d'avance.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your notation, what's *V$CCV* and *VC$CV* ? Could you be a little more clear on that part? It would make answering your question easier.

Comment: @TeleportingGoat V = vowel, $ = syllable break, C = consonant. lmc has omitted the /k/ of *constant*, though.

Comment: "Constant" is very much / /kɔ̃s.tɑ̃/ for me. The /ɔ̃/ is very clearly long in my pronunciation, which only happens in closed syllables.

Comment: Actually, I'd extend that to any word internal /sC/ cluster: preceding vowels all show the allophonic variant you'd expect from a closed syllable: espoir [ɛs.pwɑːʀ̻] rather than \*[e.spwɑːʀ̻], austère [o̝ːs.t̪ɛːʀ̥] rather than \*[o̝.st̪ɛːʀ̥], histoire [ɪs.t̪wɑːʀ̻] rather than [i.st̪wɑːʀ̻]. Trying to analyse them as /V.sC/ seems like trying too hard to make word internal syllabic onsets match word initial ones that's at odds with the fact of the language (as I speak it at least)

Comment: @Eauquidort Je dois réfléchir sur ça...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to what's known as the [Maximal Onset Principle](http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Maximal_Onset_Principle): when dividing syllables, we place as long a cluster in the onset as possible, *provided* that it doesn't violate the phonotactics of the language.

As you might imagine, the condition is the hard part to define. What's allowed and what isn't?

Here's a case where there's no violation: if we take the word *bacon* /bakɔ̃/, the principle demands that we put the /k/ in the onset of the second syllable since French syllables can begin with /k/.

Here's a case where there is a violation: if we take the word *strengthen* /ˈstrɛŋθən/, the principle demands that we put only the /θ/ in the second syllable since nasal + fricative is not attested in English.

So then looking at *constant* and *actif*, we would ask for each of them, how much of that cluster can we fit in the onset? And it turns out that we can put /st/ together into the onset for *constant*, given words like *stage*. However, we can't get both /kt/ into the onset for *actif*, since we don't find any word that begins with "kt". In fact, two [stops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_consonant) in a row is generally rare. Hence, we are forced to divide the syllable between /k/ and /t/.

---

A couple of notes apply. First, you might ask: surely we can come up with a rule that determines allowable onsets? Do we really have to look at the inventory of words to look for attestations?

- This is something that linguists do indeed wonder, and there are certain tentative rules, such as "the cluster must always increase in [sonority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonority_hierarchy) in an onset and decrease in an onset" — one problem being that the onset cluster /str/ should violate that rule since /s/ is more sonorous than /t/ but less than /r/.
- Moreover, these rules also vary between languages: in English, we eliminate the /p/ in *pneumatic*, *psychology*, and *pterodactyl*, but in French, words like *pneu*, *psychologue*, and *ptérodactyl* all have a pronounced /p/ — the last being particularly interesting since it's two stops in a row, which as we just saw above is not too common.
- And they also vary over time; the onset /s/ + stop has a troubled history in Romance languages, leading to phenomena like the Greek name *Stephanos* turning into *Esteban* in Spanish and both *Étienne* and *Stéphane* in French depending on the phonotactics at the different times the word was re-imported.

Second, even the Maximal Onset Principle has its detractors. One way that we can test whether the syllable is a real cognitive entity or a mere abstraction of our analysis is through [priming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priming_(psychology)). The priming effect on a word has been observed to be stronger if you use a complete syllable of the word rather than *stopping short* at a fragment, and similarly if you use a complete syllable but do not *add* part of the next syllable.

- For example, *balcon* is primed most effectively by /bal/, and less by /ba/ or /balk/.
- However, there's evidence for [ambisyllabicity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ambisyllabicity) as well, in which a segment belongs to both a coda and an onset. The English word *balloon* turns out to be primed equally well by /bə/ or /bəl/. This is not the case with the French word *balloune*, which is primed better by /ba/ than by /bal/.
- Hence, even the concept of the syllable may not be consistent across languages.